# Using qooxdoo to extend non-qooxdoo class - cannot access property in constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, qooxdoo

I am using Qooxdoo to extend a class which is not part of Qooxdoo. The class which is being extended has a property named "graphics".

When I create an instance of the class, I can access the property without a problem. I can also access it in a member function. But I cannot access it in the constructor.

My questions:

Why can I not access the property in question inside the constructor? Is there a way I can do?

Is it generally a good idea to use qooxdoo to extend non-qooxdoo classes, or is it going to bite me in unexpected ways? I have very little experience with qooxdoo.

For better understanding, here is the code in question:

This **DOES NOT** work, results in "this.graphics is undefined":

```
qx.Class.define('l5o.Sprite',{
    extend : Sprite,

    construct : function(){
        this.graphics.beginFill( 0xff0000 );
        this.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
    }

});

var mysprite = new l5o.Sprite;
```

This **DOES** work:

```
qx.Class.define('l5o.Sprite',{
    extend : Sprite,

    members : {
        init : function(){
            this.graphics.beginFill( 0xff0000 );
            this.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
        }
    }

});

var mysprite = new l5o.Sprite;
mysprite.init();
```

This **DOES** also work:

```
qx.Class.define('l5o.Sprite',{
    extend : Sprite
});

var mysprite = new l5o.Sprite;
mysprite.graphics.beginFill( 0xff0000 );
mysprite.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
```

Comment: Workaround: Added the following line as first line of constructor function: `Sprite.apply(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head: call the base constructor in the derived class'es constructor (add `this.base(arguments)` as the first line of the constructor, if memory serves - or look it up in the documentation), otherwise chances are your graphics property is undefined at the time you call methods on it. Both cases that work don't override the argument-less constructor, so the base class constructor does get called in these cases.

From your experience with other languages you'd probably expect the base class constructor to be called by default before the constructor of the subclass is called. That's not happening automatically with qooxdoo - you need to ask the framework maintainers why.